# Variable Size Rows in JXTreeTable

Tags: java, swing, renderer, swingx, jxtreetable

Is it possible to have variable size rows in JXTreeTable, if yes then how ? , I'm trying to change the height of the row on TreeExpansionEvent (As shown below) :

```
public void treeExpanded(TreeExpansionEvent e)
{
      for (int i = 0; i < table.getRowCount(); i++) {
            System.out.println("Value of img"+table.getValueAt(i,22));

            if (table.getValueAt(i, 22) != null) {
                table.setRowHeight(i,40);
            table.repaint();
            table.revalidate();

            }
        }
}
```

On running the code i get below Exception :

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: variable height rows not supported
    at org.jdesktop.swingx.JXTreeTable.setRowHeight(JXTreeTable.java:1321)
    at ims.View.ViewImages.treeExpanded(ViewImages.java:559)
    at org.jdesktop.swingx.event.TreeExpansionBroadcaster.fireTreeExpanded(TreeExpansionBroadcaster.java:85)
    at org.jdesktop.swingx.event.TreeExpansionBroadcaster.treeExpanded(TreeExpansionBroadcaster.java:68)
    at javax.swing.JTree.fireTreeExpanded(JTree.java:2766)
    at javax.swing.JTree.setExpandedState(JTree.java:3616)
    at org.jdesktop.swingx.JXTreeTable$TreeTableCellRenderer.setExpandedState(JXTreeTable.java:2921)
    at javax.swing.JTree.expandPath(JTree.java:2204)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTreeUI.toggleExpandState(BasicTreeUI.java:2266)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTreeUI.handleExpandControlClick(BasicTreeUI.java:2253)
```

Pls help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`JXTreeTable` does not support variable row height. Documentation for [setRowHeight()](http://download.java.net/javadesktop/swinglabs/releases/weekly/week-44-2006-10-29/swingx/javadoc/org/jdesktop/swingx/JXTreeTable.html#setRowHeight%28int,%20int%29) states:

> Throws UnsupportedOperationException because variable height rows are
>   not supported.

Also see the answer in this [thread](http://www.java.net/forum/topic/javadesktop/java-desktop-technologies/swinglabs/jxtreetable-variable-row-height) by @kleopatra regarding this feature.